# Static linkage usage in c++ linux: do I need to recompile everything each time I change library?

Tags: c++, static-linking, eclipse-cdt

I have a program which statically links to another library in linux using -L(mylib.a) when compiling (using eclipse cdt).

To my meager understanding, the fact that the link is static means that the library is inserted into my binary. Does this mean that if I make a change to mylib I need to recompile my binary?
I assume so, but I wanted to make sure, as it is a big overhead in time. Note that if a change was made to mylib, then eclipse recognizes that it needs to be recompiled, but it doesn't recognize that the binary itself needs to be recompiled, even though it links to the mylib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You should rebuild your code with the modified library to produce the binary which links to the new and updated library.

The building of a project can be broken in to two milestone phases:
**Compilation:**
During this stage the compiler compiles each Translation Unit. It checks the source code for valid syntax etc and produces object files.These object files contain the assembly code output of the source code.

**Linking:**
During this stage the linker links together the object files and the libraries to generate an executable.

When a application or project uses a static library it includes the header file which is typically called as library interface which contains the list of api and other construct which the application uses.The application also needs to link against the library file.

Obviously, if the interfaces are intact ie the library header file included by your application is unchanged, a compilation is not required but you just need to link to the updated library.

However, I dont think there is a way to just relink updated libraries through eclipse IDE so you should rebuild your project which would essentially do the needful.
i.e:
recompile your project and relink the new library to it or
just relink the new library to your project.

Comment: Linking is _not_ part of compiling, though it's typically done with the compiler command too.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I sure know Compilation & Linking are two separate and distinct processes. And sure both can ne done individually from command line but I dont think they can be done individually in eclipse which OP uses & hence the answer.

Comment: Maybe "rebuild" is less controversial than "recompile".

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes, Agreed. that would be more appropriate in this case.Perhaps, I will edit the answer to explain more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

If you did not change the interface of the library (i.e. the headers), only a re-link is enough.

Comment: thanks. Do you have any idea how to perform only re-link in eclipse?